# How do I calculate "g(x)" by a group of "x" while I run the "min" method on "g"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, min

There's a group of indices (`x`) which I'd like to use as arguments in a method called `g`, like this: `g(x)`.

I'd like to replace each return with the next one, **only** if it's less than the previous one.

I'm using a `while` loop, but each time I assign the return of the `g` method I lose the value of the previous return.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: When writing a question you can use the [question wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard).

Answer (score 0):

Is this kind of what you meant?

```
def g(x, a, b, c, d):
    return ( x * x * x ) * a + ( x * x ) * b + x * c  + d

gB = float("inf")   
usedXs = []
for v0 in range(-10, 10):   
    for v1 in range(-10, 10):
        for v2 in range(-10, 10):
            for v3 in range (-10, 10):
                for v4 in range(-10 ,10):
                    gA = g(v0, v1, v2, v3, v4)
                    if(gA < gB):
                        gB = gA
                        usedXs = [v0, v1, v2, v3, v4]

print(usedXs)
print(gB)
```

Which outputs

> [-10, 9, -10, 9, -10]
>   -10100

Comment: Up-vote for even being able to answer this question, I'm amazed by your effort, given the complete and total lack of information provided by the OP. That being said, this is a ridiculous amount of white space and nested `for` loops for any task, especially one that only returns a single `list` and `int`.